# Who could I denormalize this?

Tags: statistics, python

I am trying to denormalize the following data:

```
original = [37.31, 373.02,  57.4 , 216.61,  67.44, 159.21,  77.49, 113.29,
        91.84,  86.03, 123.41,  84.59, 162.15,  96.07, 215.25,  86.03,
       261.17,  70.24, 285.56,  68.81, 337.22,  68.81, 411.84,  93.2 ,
       454.89, 107.55, 496.5 , 255.35, 513.72, 262.53, 552.47, 292.66,
       586.  , 324.23, 586.  , 381.63, 586.  , 449.08, 586.  , 453.38,
       578.3 , 616.97, 518.03, 621.27, 444.84, 624.14, 340.09, 625.58,
       136.32, 625.58,   1.43, 632.75,   7.17, 555.26,   5.74, 414.64]

normalized = [0.0636689 , 0.582844  , 0.0979522 , 0.338453  , 0.115085  ,
       0.248766  , 0.132235  , 0.177016  , 0.156724  , 0.134422  ,
       0.210597  , 0.132172  , 0.276706  , 0.150109  , 0.367321  ,
       0.134422  , 0.445683  , 0.10975   , 0.487304  , 0.107516  ,
       0.575461  , 0.107516  , 0.702799  , 0.145625  , 0.776263  ,
       0.168047  , 0.84727   , 0.398984  , 0.876655  , 0.410203  ,
       0.942782  , 0.457281  , 1.        , 0.506609  , 1.        ,
       0.596297  , 1.        , 0.701688  , 1.        , 0.708406  ,
       0.98686   , 0.964016  , 0.88401   , 0.970734  , 0.759113  ,
       0.975219  , 0.580358  , 0.977469  , 0.232628  , 0.977469  ,
       0.00244027, 0.988672  , 0.0122355 , 0.867594  , 0.00979522,
       0.647875  ]
```

I don't know the formula used to get the normalized form of the first one, but I tried the following two methods.

**By Mode**

```
original_np = np.array(original)
escaled_mode = original_np / mode(original_np)
```

and I get this result

```
array([0.06366894, 0.6365529 , 0.09795222, 0.36964164, 0.11508532,
       0.27168942, 0.13223549, 0.19332765, 0.15672355, 0.14680887,
       0.21059727, 0.14435154, 0.27670648, 0.16394198, 0.36732082,
       0.14680887, 0.44568259, 0.11986348, 0.48730375, 0.11742321,
       0.57546075, 0.11742321, 0.70279863, 0.15904437, 0.7762628 ,
       0.18353242, 0.84726962, 0.43575085, 0.87665529, 0.44800341,
       0.94278157, 0.4994198 , 1.        , 0.55329352, 1.        ,
       0.65124573, 1.        , 0.76634812, 1.        , 0.77368601,
       0.98686007, 1.05284983, 0.88401024, 1.06018771, 0.75911263,
       1.06508532, 0.58035836, 1.06754266, 0.23262799, 1.06754266,
       0.00244027, 1.07977816, 0.01223549, 0.94754266, 0.00979522,
       0.70757679])
```

The result is near an odd position and probably the error is about the way of the language makes the division, but the even numbers are enough far to imagine that this way is not the corrected.

I tried the following formula

```
(original_np - original_np.min()) / (original_np.max() - original_np.min())
```

but I get a wrong result

```
[0.0568333 , 0.58859216, 0.08865552, 0.34084141, 0.1045587 ,
       0.2499208 , 0.12047773, 0.17718431, 0.14320788, 0.13400494,
       0.19321422, 0.13172401, 0.25457771, 0.14990813, 0.3386872 ,
       0.13400494, 0.41142368, 0.10899385, 0.45005702, 0.10672876,
       0.53188557, 0.10672876, 0.65008237, 0.1453621 , 0.71827283,
       0.16809225, 0.78418235, 0.4022049 , 0.81145853, 0.4135779 ,
       0.87283786, 0.4613033 , 0.92594881, 0.51130964, 0.92594881,
       0.60223025, 0.92594881, 0.70906989, 0.92594881, 0.71588101,
       0.91375214, 0.97500475, 0.8182855 , 0.98181588, 0.7023538 ,
       0.98636191, 0.5364316 , 0.98864284, 0.21366344, 0.98864284,
       0.        , 1.        , 0.00909206, 0.87725718, 0.00682697,
       0.65451752]
```

What is the relation with the mode? or how can I try to get the way of conversion from original, to normalized?

Thanks

Comment: If you divide every original term by the normalized one you'll get $[586, 640, 586, 640,\cdots]$ (2D datas?).

Comment: The mode of odd terms is $586$ while the mode of even terms is $632.75$. This should help you to conclude!

Comment: 632.75 is the max no the mode, and I am not sure that the this was used, because, as you can see the there are only 1, and I divide odd terms by 586 and even terms by 632.75 I will need 5th 1 but I only have 4.

Comment: You are right I indicated the maximum not the mode. Perhaps that the tolerated maximum for even terms is $640$ (for the odd terms $586$ is obtained more than once : saturation?). The $640,586$ values could be 'fixed' values but I'll let you play with that...

Comment: @RaymondManzoni How did you get "the mode of even terms is $632.75$"?  Your $640$ to two decimal places looks correct for the even terms

Comment: @Henry: I searched the maximum for even and odd terms and obtained this but to get the correct 'normalized' terms had to divide by $640$.

Comment: I was finding more information about that numbers and are width and heigth of the image.